# How to get the pagination last number with soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hi I have a web here https://alfagift.id/find/ayam where I have ben trying to get the last page number. However to no avail.

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

#get soup
ua = UserAgent()
USER_AGENT = ua.random
headers = {"User-Agent" : str(USER_AGENT),"Accept-Encoding": "*","Connection": "keep-alive"}
resp = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, "html.parser")

#get page
pages=[]
page = soup.find_all("a",{class:"page-link"})
for p in page:
 pages.append(int(p.text))
maxpage = int(page).max()
```

However this isn't returning anything. How would I find the pagination correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pagination, along with all products, is added dynamically by JS from a JSON.

To get the total number of pages, try this:

```py
import json

import requests
import re

print(
    json.loads(
        re.search(
            r"var pageList = (.*);",
            requests.get("https://alfagift.id/find/ayam").text,
        ).group(1),
    )["totalPage"]
)
```

Output:

```
5
```